# How does CSS3 flexbox negative-flex work?

Tags: css, flexbox

I started playing around with CSS3 flex box recently, I've read through many resources and played around with it myself. I've looked through: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/

Specifically I am having trouble with the flex property on the child elements:

```
flex: <positive-flex> <negative-flex> <preferred-size>
```

I can't seem to understand how the negative-flex parameter works. The positive-flex makes sense as it distributes space proportionally from the parent element to the children.

The negative-flex, from what I understand is supposed to shrink elements when they overflow the parent. However, I have not been able to get this to work. Any help understanding would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code I've been testing with: http://jsfiddle.net/nxzQQ/2/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#container > :nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;

    -webkit-flex: 1 0 0px;
    flex: 1 0 0px;
}

#container > :nth-child(2) {
    background-color: blue;

    -webkit-flex: 2 0 0px;
    flex: 2 0 0px;
}

#container > :nth-child(3) {
    background-color: orange;

    -webkit-flex: 1 0 0px;
    flex: 1 0 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In an article from Opera on flexbox, negative flex is described as such:

```
#first {
  flex: 1 1 400px;
}

#second {
  flex: 2 3 600px;
}

#third {
  flex: 1 2 400px;
}
```

> The negative flex values, despite their name, are positive values —
>   the second unitless values in the above declarations. These only come
>   into play when the children overflow their parent container in the
>   main axis direction. They also act as proportion values, but this time
>   they specify the proportion of the "overflow amount" (the amount the
>   children overflow their container by) that will be deducted off the
>   size of each child, to bring the overall size down to equal the size
>   of the parent — in effect, to stop the overflow.
>
> Let's say that the parent container is 1100 pixels along the main
>   axis. This being the case, our above children would overflow it by 300
>   pixels (they equal 1400 pixels along the main axis, in total). Because
>   of the negative flex values set on them:
>
> - The first child would get 1/6th of the overflow amount removed from it, which is 50 pixels. Its computed value would therefore be 350
>     pixels.
> - The second child would get 3/6th of the overflow amount removed from it, which is 150 pixels. Its computed value would therefore be
>     450 pixels.
> - The third child would get 2/6th of the overflow amount removed from it, which is 100 pixels. Its computed value would therefore be 300
>     pixels.
>
> So a higher negative flex value actually results in a smaller element!

Source:  http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/flexbox-basics/